# CSS hover issues

Tags: html, css

hover is not working on my image. I honestly do not know why. Image is in a div class called portfolio as seen by code below

```css
  

 .portfolio {

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.portfolio__item {
  background: var(--clr-accent);
}

.portfolio__img{

  transition: transform 750ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1),
  opacity 250ms linear;
}

.portfolio__img:hover {

  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: .75;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code: `opacity 250ms linear` is missing a colon.  It should be `opacity: 250ms linear`.

Comment: Also, there should be no space between `:` and `hover`.

Comment: where is the `portfolio__img` class

Comment: See my answer for a working snippet.

Comment: still did not work.. even after i updated. how do i post the updated version for you to see?

Comment: I think the best option moving forward is for you create a [mcve] in the snippet so the community can see _exactly_ the issue you are facing to help you resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few mis-types in your CSS:

1. There should be no space between the colon and `hover`-- it is a pseudo-selector written as `:hover`:

(I removed the line regarding the colon after `opacity` because I misread it, thanks to [@pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete) for the correction.

```css
.portfolio__item {
  background: var(--clr-accent);
}

.portfolio__img:hover { /* no space here between : and hover */

  transition: transform 750ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1),
              opacity 250ms linear;
}

.portfolio__img:hover { /* no space here between : and hover */

  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: .75;
}
```

Also, as [@bouh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10491674/bouh) points out in the comments, there is no element with the class `.portfolio__img` in your mark-up, so no elements will be matched by this selector.

If we combine these two things we should have a working example:

```css
.portfolio__item {
  background: var(--clr-accent);
}

.portfolio__img:hover {
  transition: transform 750ms cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1), opacity 250ms linear;
}

.portfolio__img:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: .75;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <a href="#" class="portfolio__item">
    <p class="portfolio__img" src="../imagefolder/me.jpeg" alt="me">test test test</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The hover is being carried out on (portfolio__img).
The class of the div is (portfolio__item).

That is the problem.
Try replacing class name with portfolio__img